# how to deploy database

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment

Hi what is the best way to deploy database script to my client pc? i have installed the app and have the sql management studio installed at my client pc. Everything went smooth except when i need to update the database. How do i update the database without having me to go to their pc to run the .sql update script. This question applies when my app is used at other country.

For updating code is fine as i am using the ClickOnce.
This is a window based app.

Please help

Comment: I think you should shed some light on the situation. Is this a client server application? Are you sharing a development environment?

Comment: opss.. i forgot to mention that it is a window based app. The database is installed at the client PC.

Comment: So every client that would use the application needs to have a SQL Server instance installed? You are aware you can centralize your SQL Server so every client connects to the same?

Comment: @Peter: thanks for the reply. Ya every client would have seperate SQL instance installed as each client is managing their own database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ship the SQL file with your application, and have application startup logic that always checks a certain location for scripts that need to be run. It could be as simple as checking a [application path]\MigrationScripts folder for all .sql files. If files are found, read in the contents and execute against the database.

Once the check (and potential database updates) are complete, continue loading the application.

Sample Code (untested), and a very basic implementation:

```
public class Migration
{
    private string _migrationPath = @"C:\temp\MigrationSteps"; //change
    private string[] _sqlFiles = null;

    public Migration()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public Migration(string path)
    {
        _migrationPath = path;
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _sqlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_migrationPath, "*.sql");
    }

    public bool Run()
    {
        bool success = true;

        foreach (string sqlFile in _sqlFiles)
        {
            ExecuteRun(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
        }

        return success; //Do something with this value
    }

    public bool CleanUp()
    {
        //Put some logic here to "clean up" files that have already been run.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private bool ExecuteRun(string sqlText)
    {
        //Call your data access library and execute the sqlText
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Migration migration = new Migration();
if (migration.Run())
{
    migration.CleanUp();
}
else
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: @BrandonZeider: This sounds to be a good idea. I can create a New folder call MigrationScripts in my project and put those update database script in that folder. But where should i write the checking script to check all the .sql file in the MigrationScript folder? Could you provide some example in code?

Comment: You would put the logic in your Main entry point. Do you use a splash screen? I will update my answer with some code to check for sql files.

Comment: @BrandonZeider: This sound good. Let me try it out and i will come back to you. I think i will need to have a splash screen for this. One question - When i call the ExecuteRun() to run the sql script, do i need to put in the Sql username and password to run those script?

Comment: Yep - I assume your migration scripts are going to be things like altering and adding tables, right? So the text of the file will be something like "Alter Table1 Add Column1 Int".

Whatever you're doing, you will need to authenticate with the database, so just authenticate the same way you currently do (Windows auth/SQL auth). 

For your splash screen, just google around, there are lots of examples on how to build one. Here's one: http://exceptionalcode.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/splash-screen-for-windows-forms-application/

Comment: @BrandonZeider: What i currently do when updating database script is i go to my client pc and login to the management studio with username and password. Then i copy the .sql update script and RUN. If by using your suggestion by authenticate using SQL auth, am i going to write my uesrname and password in the .sql script? How? please advice.

Comment: Not into your SQL script - you would need to store a connection string that would have your username and password in it. Here are some tutorial links that will give you sample code. Notice that when the SqlConnection is instantiated, a connection string is passed into the constructor. http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson02.aspx

Comment: Use this website to find the structure of your connection string: http://connectionstrings.com/. It should be something similar to this format: "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

Comment: @BrandonZeider: Hi i have successfully execute the sql changes script as this  foreach (string s in sqlFiles)
                {
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(s);
                    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                    file.OpenText().Close();    BUT when i do the CleanUp() process foreach (string s in sqlFiles)
                {
                    File.Delete(s);
                } it failed to remove the sql script in my folder saying that the file is still currently in use.

Comment: Don't use FileInfo. Instead just do: string script = File.ReadAllText(s); inside your ForEach loop. The FileInfo object still has the file, so it can't delete it. Once you are ready to delete, do File.Delete(s);

Comment: @BrandonZeider: You deserved the glory !!! Excellent idea. Thank you so much for this excellent idea. Work like a charm. :)

Comment: @BrandonZeider: One question, how do i point the location to my client project folder path?  private string _migrationPath = @"C:\temp\MigrationSteps"; //change. When i published my updateDatabase script using clickonce, the script is in the project folder. I do not able to COPY ALWAYS that files to the bin.

Comment: So did I answer your question?

My understanding of ClickOnce is that it will install to the documents location (OS specific). You can use Application.StartupPath() to get the path of the executable that started the application. From there I'm guessing you could use a path relative to that location.

Comment: @BrandonZeider: thanks for the reply. But when i do clickonce, i only publish the .exe and the .dll. How do i publish the folder with all .sql script? I cannot do COPY ALWAYS the whole folder. If i do not publish the whole folder, then how does the code point to that specific folder which store the .sql files?

Comment: I don't know how to publish the folder with clickonce, I would think that's possible though...

Comment: @BrandonZeider: Hi, i think i am having problem on the ExecuteRun(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));  i can successfully execute it by `Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn)); server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script); ` .. But this requires the using of 
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common; which the dll is too bulky when i do the deployment.  Since i am doing LINQ,  LenDataContext db = new LenDataContext(); Could it be something like db.Execute(script) ? But this failed as it requires the object. please advice

Comment: @BrandonZeider: Thanks for the reply. I have solved that by changing to  db.ExecuteCommand(script);. It works well . I can saved up almost 8 MB of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management dll. Thanks again